# How do you rename columns if they exist in the data frame?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am reading in an Excel that gets periodically updated with new columns. I need to conditionally evaluate the renaming piece depending on if each column is present. Otherwise move on. How do you conditionally update the naming, say if someone didn't yet add in this months data, `current_month_program_acceptance_rate`? So it doesn’t break.

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

dataset_ex <- data.frame(current_month_program_acceptance_rate = c(22.2,44.2,87),
                         last_month_program_acceptance_rate = c(27.8,65.8,34.5))


data_variable <- "June"
last_month <- "April"

# How do you only evaluate this if column is present and continue on if other columns are not present

dataset_ex <-
  dataset_ex %>%
  rename("{data_variable}_program_acceptance_rate" := current_month_program_acceptance_rate)

dataset_ex <-
  dataset_ex %>%
  rename("{last_month}_program_acceptance_rate" := last_month_program_acceptance_rate)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R if a column is not present in a data frame it will evaluate as `NULL`.

```r
> dataset_ex$this_column_is_not_here
NULL
```

So you can use `is.null` to check if the column is present.

```
if (!is.null(dataset_ex$current_month_program_acceptance_rate)){
  dataset_ex <-
    dataset_ex %>%
    dplyr::rename("{data_variable}_program_acceptance_rate" := "current_month_program_acceptance_rate")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `rename_with`: ie

```
df1 <- data.frame(last_month_program_acceptance_rate = 0.8)
```

Note that `df1` has only one available column:

```
data_variable <- "June"
last_month <- "April"
maintained_part <- "program_acceptance_rate"
nms <- paste(c(data_variable, last_month), maintained_part, sep = '_')
names(nms) <- paste(c("current_month", 'last_month'),maintained_part, sep = '_')

df1 <- df1 %>%
  rename_with(~str_replace_all(.,nms))
df1
  
April_program_acceptance_rate
1                           0.8
```

We can see that only the available columns are replaced:

Now `df2` has all variables:

```
df2 <- data.frame(last_month_program_acceptance_rate = 0.8,
                  current_month_program_acceptance_rate = 0.9)

df2 <- df2 %>% rename_with(~str_replace_all(.,nms))
df2

  April_program_acceptance_rate June_program_acceptance_rate
1                           0.8                          0.9
```